# Pass args for solve_ivp (new SciPy ODE API)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, odeint

For solving simple ODEs using SciPy, I used to use the odeint function, with form:

```
scipy.integrate.odeint(func, y0, t, args=(), Dfun=None, col_deriv=0, full_output=0, ml=None, mu=None, rtol=None, atol=None, tcrit=None, h0=0.0, hmax=0.0, hmin=0.0, ixpr=0, mxstep=0, mxhnil=0, mxordn=12, mxords=5, printmessg=0)[source]
```

where a simple function to be integrated could include additional arguments of the form:

```
def dy_dt(t, y, arg1, arg2):
    # processing code here
```

In SciPy 1.0, it seems the *ode* and *odeint* funcs have been replaced by a newer *solve_ivp* method.

```
scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, method='RK45', t_eval=None, dense_output=False, events=None, vectorized=False, **options)
```

However, this doesn't seem to offer an *args* parameter, nor any indication in the documentation as to implementing the passing of args.

Therefore, I wonder if arg passing is possible with the new API, or is this a feature that has yet to be added? (It would seem an oversight to me if this features has been intentionally removed?)

Reference:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't seem like the new function has an `args` parameter. As a workaround you can create a wrapper like

```
def wrapper(t, y):
    orig_func(t,y,hardcoded_args)
```

and pass that in.

Comment: Thanks, although this seems a serious issue with solve_ivp (the wrapper would like increase overheads and be slower in my application). Consequently, I'll just go back to the old API. I wonder why the devs made such a backwards move?

Comment: Agreed, this is too complicated for novice and causal users. Not sure what the developers where thinking. Even worse they don't even provide an example in the docs for this very common situation.

Answer (score 15):

Relatively recently there appeared a similar question on [scipy's github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8352#issuecomment-362918089). Their solution is to use `lambda`:

```
solve_ivp(fun=lambda t, y: fun(t, y, *args), ...)
```

And they argue that there is already enough overhead for this not to matter.

Comment: I read the comments and it looks like many people aren't happy with the use of lambda compared to the simple arg=(). They still done have example, since I don't use lambda I'm still not sure what to do. Could you post a complete example, I think a lot of people would benefit.

Answer (score 6):

Recently the 'args' option was added to solve_ivp, see here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8352#issuecomment-535689344

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: You should perhaps add directly that it is expected to be available from scipy version  1.4 on.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, I think you can also do this but I'm not sure why you would bother since the other two options posted here are perfectly fine.

```
from functools import partial
fun = partial(dy_dt, arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2)
scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, method='RK45', t_eval=None, dense_output=False, events=None, vectorized=False, **options)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [Javier-Acuna's ultra-brief, ultra-useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58281925/7952027), the feature that you (as well as I) desire has recently been added. This was [announced on Github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8352#issuecomment-535689344) by none other than the great Warren Weckesser (See his [Github](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser))  himself.
Anyway, jokes aside the [docstring of solve_ivp](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) has an example using it in for the `[Lotka-Volterra equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations)

> solve_ivp(
>       fun,
>       t_span,
>       y0,
>       method='RK45',
>       t_eval=None,
>       dense_output=False,
>       events=None,
>       vectorized=False,
>       args=None,
>       **options,
>   )

So, just include args as a tuple. In your case

```
args = (arg1, arg2)
```

Please don't use my answer unless your scipy version >= 1.4 .
There is no args parameter in solve_ivp for versions below it. I have personally experienced my answer failing for version 1.2.1.

The implementation by [zahabaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55720088/7952027) would probably still work fine in case your scipy version < 1.4

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Cleb's answer, here's an example for using the `lambda t,y: fun(t,y,args)` method. We set up the function handle that returns the rhs of a second order homogeneous ODE with two parameters. Then we feed it to our solver, along with a couple options.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def rhs_2nd_order_ode(t, y, a, b):
    """
    2nd order ODE function handle for use with scipy.integrate.solve_ivp
    Solves u'' + au'+ bu = 0 after reducing order with y[0]=u and y[1]=u'.

    :param t: dependent variable
    :param y: independent variables
    :param a: a
    :param b: b
    :return: Returns the rhs of y[0]' = y[1] and y[1]' = -a*y[1] - b*y[0]
    """
    return [y[1], -a*y[1] - b*y[0]]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t_span = (0, 10)
    t_eval = np.linspace(t_span[0], t_span[1], 100)
    y0 = [0, 1]
    a = 1
    b = 2
    sol = integrate.solve_ivp(lambda t,y: rhs_2nd_order_ode(t,y,a,b), t_span, y0, 
                              method='RK45', t_eval=t_eval)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0])
    ax.set(xlabel='t',ylabel='y')
```