# Use solve_ivp() from Scipy with dynamic args

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use `solve_ivp()` function to solve for an ODE with state-dependent args. The idea is to update the ODE at each time instants given the current state of the trajectory.

Given the ODE model as the following:

```
def model(t, y, arg1, arg2):
    '''
    Some Dynamics model that includes arg1 and arg 2
    '''
    return dy_dt
```

The `arg1` and `arg2` are calculated using some other function:

```
def gen_args(y):
    '''
    Calculate arg1 and arg2 based on the state y
    '''
    return arg1, arg2
```

Then I want to integrate over the ODE model:

```
scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(model, t_span, y0, method='RK45', t_eval=None, dense_output=False, events=None, vectorized=False)
```

What would be a nice way to implement this?

I have checked similar questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245765/pass-args-for-solve-ivp-new-scipy-ode-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841367/using-scipy-solve-ivp-for-a-function-with-extra-arguments), But all the args are external constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to call `gen_args` in `model`:

```
def model(t, y):
    arg1, arg2 = gen_args(y)
    dy_dt = ...
    return dy_dt
```

Answer (score 0):

*Adding on to @Warren Weckesser answer*

It makes very less sense to include any state and (or) time-dependent arguments in the args parameter of 'solve_ivp'. They should be included in the 
'fun' parameter of 'solve_ivp' itself.
Including any state and (or) time-dependent arguments analogous to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60267581/7952027) inspired by @Warren Weckesser is not possible. The args parameter in

> solve_ivp( fun, t_span, y0, method='RK45', t_eval=None, dense_output=False, events=None, vectorized=False, args=None, **options, )

can only take in a tuple of constant arguments (for example floats, integers, etc)

Comment: Nitpick: While it is the probably the most common use-case, it is not true that the values passed to `args` must be constants (floats, integers, etc).  They can be arbitrary Python objects; `solve_ivp` doesn't care, it just passes them on to the user's functions.  For example, one could pass a function in `args`.