# solve_ivp Error: "missing 2 required positional arguments:"

Tags: python, solver

The function that I am using for solve_ivp is defined as:

`def ydot(t,y,kappa4,kappa16):`

Upon using solve_ivp as below:

`sol=solve_ivp(ydot,[0,10],initial_condition(),args=(50,100))`

I get the following error:

`ydot() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'kappa4' and 'kappa16'`

I am not able debug the code even though I have defined the function `ydot` the way scipy documentation for solve_ivp defines (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html)

There's even an example in the end of the documentation that demonstrates the passing of arguments implemented in the same way as I have done.

I believe the problem is somewhere in the two above pieces of the code I have provided from an otherwise long code.

Comment: Hi Angad, even if 'I believe the problem is somewhere in the two above pieces of the code I have provided from an otherwise long code.' , please be kind to us and provide an MWE (minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks. I am new to stack overflow. Didn't know about this. Consider the following minimal example:
`def ydot(t,y,a):
    return -a*y`

`sol=solve_ivp(ydot,[0,10],[5],args=(10))`

I still get the same error for my argument **a**.

Comment: Does my answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to replicate the error with scipy 1.1.0 .
Upgrading scipy to the latest version via cmd (`pip install scipy==1.4.1`) solved that error message for me.

Then the minimal reproducible example gave another error:

> TypeError: ydot() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

Which was solved by the solution given by Tejas. The full working minimal script is hence:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def ydot(t,y,a): return -a*y

sol=solve_ivp(ydot,[0,10],[5],args=(8,))
print(sol.y)
```

Comment: I updated scipy package using `!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} scipy` on my jupyter notebook (currently using os 10.13.4 High Sierra) referring the article [https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/] and it updated the scipy package to 1.2.1 instead of 1.4.1

Comment: perhaps scipy 1.2.1 also does the job? In any case i have no experience with macOS but probably you can also use "conda/pip install scipy==1.4.1"?

Comment: The error is unresolved with scipy 1.2.1 as also pointed by @Tejas in the post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245765/pass-args-for-solve-ivp-new-scipy-ode-api?rq=1]

Comment: Is it resolved for you with scipy 1.4.1 ? Can you make the upgrade?

Comment: The command "conda/pip install scipy==1.4.1", is it supposed to be executed from Jupyter notebook?

Comment: you need to execute "pip install scipy==1.4.1" from the command line / terminal / any way you call it in macOS

Comment: @Joris Upgrding scipy solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same issue recently.
But the great [Warren Weckesser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser)
[helped](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/10098#issuecomment-588224751) me out. 
Change

> args=(10)

to

> args=(10,)

and your MWE will work fine.
This happens because of tuples with a single element.
For reference see pg 30 of Python tutorial pdf (Release 3.5.1) on python.org